# PANDAS read_sql faults when running NOSE test - Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, nose

Have you seen this pandas sqlite error? `ArgumentError("Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '/')`? It only happens in a NOSE test.

From the other questions on SO, the err seems to be related to sqlite. But I can't tell how since there are no others using a simple sqlite3 db like I am.

In my unit test, I call a class method that reads from an sqlite3 DB via `pandas read_sql`. It works perfectly in any python session as well as Jupyter notebook. But for some reason when I run the code through a nosetest, nose tells me there's an Argument Error. And I cannot reproduce it.

I've confirmed the DB is working properly. As I mentioned, the pd.read_sql works perfectly in any other setting.

In the method definition, I am doing the following read,

```
# get data
div_query = 'SELECT * FROM Dividends WHERE Symbol == "{stock}"'.format(stock = symbol)
div_history = pd.read_sql(div_query, con=dbcnx)
```

And in the NOSE test,

```
def test_shiftBeforeDividend():
    # here is where the err occurs
    result = filters.shiftBeforeDividend('DUK') 
    # result now equals ArgumentError("Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '/'")

def setup():
    try:    
        db = 'mydb.db'
        test_class.connectToDB(db)
        return test_class

    except Exception as e:
        return e

def teardown():
    try:
        filters.closeDBConnection(self.dbcnx[0])

    except Exception as e:
        return e

# startup
filters = setup()
```

Any ideas on how to eliminate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out after some hair pulling that the error was a simple misplaced '/' in the db file path. Hence, sqlite could not connect to a DB and all calls to the DB resulted in an error. In all the help topics I read on similar subjects, it seems that this error always results from an improper DB reference (i.e., file path). So if you run into the issue, make sure your file path exists and is correct before trying operations on your DB.